# Eclipse not deploy all the jar files for a web app

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

We have a non-trivial multi-module maven project, then have a single module maven web-app that depends on 2 modules in the larger multi module project.

When we use eclipse to deploy to tomcat, it doesn't deploy all the jars that are required (spring, camel, etc) by the projects in the multi-module projects, but the multi-module jars are present???

But if we were to do an export of a war file on the single module app it includes everything we need spring, camel, and all the multi-module jars as expected?  Why do export and deploy work differently and how can I get deploy to work the way I want.

We are using eclipse 3.6.2 with m2eclipse and other plugins.  It seems Eclipse Indigo is worst at handling maven projects than 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem that I encounter semi-regularly. Open the build path for the project, and in the Exports tab, check the Maven dependencies checkbox. Do a clean and reploy the webapp.

It may be necessary to remove & readd the webapp to the server, and I usually have to quit Eclipse and restart it.